# SQL Server Replication: How do you change the distributor?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016

I've been given the task to change the distributor to a new server for pre-existing replication (both snapshot and transaction).

- Server A:  Existing Replication (Publisher)
- Server B:  Existing Distributor
- Server C:  New Distributor

I haven't done this before and all I've done is setup the Distributor Properties on Server C to accept Server A as a Publisher.

What other steps need to happen to change the distributor please?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You cannot, you have to recreate it

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani, thanks for your help.  Can you have 2 Distributors on the same publication server?

Comment: [SQL Server Transactional Replication Moving Distribution Database – step-by-step guide](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-transactional-replication-moving-distribution-database-step-by-step-guide/) by Miroslav Dimitrov might help.