# Server 'repl_distributor' is not configured for DATA ACCESS

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016, configuration, linked-server

I have [enabled](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/234456/22336) my `repl_distributor` linked server for [data access](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/130716/22336) in both `publisher_server` and `distributor_server`.

Both servers are also configured to [allow remote connections](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/242461/22336)

On both servers I have the same output and error messages:

> Server 'repl_distributor' is not configured for DATA ACCESS.

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'remote access', 1; -- UI checkbox checked
reconfigure

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'repl_distributor', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_checkLinkedServer @server_name=N'repl_distributor'
```

[image]

```
 SELECT 
   name,
   is_data_access_enabled 
 FROM sys.servers
 where name = 'repl_distributor'
```

[image]

I have no problems with the replication I just wanted to use this `repl_distributor` as a linked server in a query.

**The question is:**

Is there a way to enable `repl_distributor` as a good linked server?

---

the query where I need to use a *linked server to the distributor server* is obviously when the [distributor_server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/290558/22336) is a different server to the `publisher_server`.

I want to find the name of the distributor job.

A - when the *distribution database* is on the same server - no problem:

```
   use publisher_database
   go

select s.srvid
      ,s.artid
      ,[is article marked for reinitialization]= CASE WHEN s.queued_reinit = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No ' END
      ,s.dest_db
      ,s.status
      ,s.distribution_jobid
      ,[distribution job name]=j.name
      ,[is job enabled]= CASE WHEN j.enabled = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No ' END
      ,[Subscription Server Name]=s.srvname
from syssubscriptions s 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
        ON job_id = s.distribution_jobid
```

[image]

B. when instead the *distribution database* is on the *distributor server* then I need to use a [linked server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/93202/22336):

```
   use publisher_database
   go
select s.srvid
      ,s.artid
      ,[is article marked for reinitialization]= CASE WHEN s.queued_reinit = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No ' END
      ,s.dest_db
      ,s.status
      ,s.distribution_jobid
      ,[distribution job name]=j.name
      ,[is job enabled]= CASE WHEN j.enabled = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No ' END
      ,[Subscription Server Name]=s.srvname
from syssubscriptions s 
INNER JOIN [my distributor server].msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
        ON job_id = s.distribution_jobid
```

[image]

Comment: yes, both in the distributor and the publisher

Comment: Sorry I misread your first sentence. I thought you said Publisher and Subscriber.

Comment: no worries, it is indeed a very very specific point, I would probably find an alternative instead of fixing it, but I will leave it for tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this to check first

```
 SELECT 
   name,
   is_data_access_enabled 
 FROM sys.servers;
```

then if value is 0 run:

```
 EXEC sp_serveroption
   @server = 'repl_distributor',
   @optname = 'DATA ACCESS',
   @optvalue = 'TRUE';
```

Comment: that's very good Luca. welcome to dba.stackexchange.com. and what would you do if it would show `yes` is_data_access_enabled is 1 but when you try to use the linked server is still complains? have a look again at the question. thanks for answering though.